# onItemClick works but onItemLongClick does not, why?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

i like to share item when long click on it, i use `onItemClick` to go to another intent and use `onItemLongClick` for share but `onItemLongClick` not work please help me

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {      
    ViewHolder ocHolder =  (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    TextView ocTextID =(TextView)ocHolder.txtID;
    TextView ocTextDsc =(TextView)ocHolder.txtDsc;

    Intent intents = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intents.setType("text/plain");
    String my_string = ocTextTitle.getText().toString();
    intents.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, my_string);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intents, "Share this text via"));

    return false;  
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
    ViewHolder ocHolder =  (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    TextView ocTextID =(TextView)ocHolder.txtID;
    TextView ocTextTitle =(TextView)ocHolder.txtTitle;

    Intent i = new Intent(hozeactivity.this, ChildList.class);
    i.putExtra("pId", ocTextID.getText().toString() );
    i.putExtra("uName", ocUser );
    i.putExtra("pass", ocPass);
    i.putExtra("isOnline", isOnline);

    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `return false;` to `return true;` to tell the View you'd be processing the event. Modify your code as follows:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {      
    ViewHolder ocHolder =  (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    TextView ocTextID =(TextView)ocHolder.txtID;
    TextView ocTextDsc =(TextView)ocHolder.txtDsc;

    Intent intents = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intents.setType("text/plain");
    String my_string = ocTextTitle.getText().toString();
    intents.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, my_string);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intents, "Share this text via"));

    return true;
```

}

Also make sure the ListView registers the setOnItemLongClickListener() :

```
myListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: Did you try logging in the OnItemLockClick() to check if it's fired. Example : public boolean onItemLongClick() Log.d("myTag", "fired");